Llamaindex load from storage optimization
I am trying to load index like this
load_index_from_storage(retrieved_sentence)
Due to the file size it is taking long time to load indices. What is the best way to optimize it? I read some where Batch loading and Parallel loading are possible but I don't know how to implement it? Could anyone help to optimize the loading process?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
